# how do I send " ´ " Character?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I tried the Code:

```
$+´:: Send {Raw}`
```

I am using QWERTZ Keyboard, windows 10, 64 bit

when I press the shift key and "´" key together, it should send "´"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this without your special keyboard, but I think this will work:

**This should send ` when <kbd>shift+´</kbd> is pressed:**

```
+´:: Send ``
```

The backtick is an escape character, so the first backtick forces the second one to be treated like a normal keystroke